Jetpack Compose Animated Radial Gradient Color
I am trying to make a custom animation and I have a specific needs.
I would like to use radialGradient brush with a list of colors and would like to animate the color position inside the gradient. Like I have Red/Green/Blue gradient which move to Blue/Red/Green and after Green/Blue/Red, etc.
Do you have any idea how to do this in jetpack Compose ?

To create an animated radial gradient color, you can use the radialGradient brush along with an animated list of colors. Below is a one way to achieve this:
@Composable
fun App1() {

    val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue)
    val durationMillis = 2000

    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "transition")
    
    val color1 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[0],
        targetValue = colors[1],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color1"
    )

    val color2 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[1],
        targetValue = colors[2],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color2"
    )

    val color3 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[2],
        targetValue = colors[0],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color3"
    )


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(400.dp)
            .background(brush = Brush.radialGradient(listOf(color1, color2, color3)))
    )
}

Demo:

To avoid unnecessary recomposition use drawBehind instead of background modifier:
@Composable
fun App2(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue)
    val durationMillis = 2000

    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "transition")

    val color1 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[0],
        targetValue = colors[1],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color1"
    )

    val color2 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[1],
        targetValue = colors[2],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color2"
    )

    val color3 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[2],
        targetValue = colors[0],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color3"
    )


    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            //.background(brush = Brush.radialGradient(listOf(color1, color2, color3)))
            .drawBehind {
                drawRect(
                    brush = Brush.radialGradient(listOf(color1, color2, color3))
                )
            }
    )
}

I think you can optimize this further by caching the brush. Try using drawWithCache for this. However, I'm not sure if this will cache anything because the colors are animated and the brush needs to be recreated each time.
@Composable
fun App3(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue)
    val durationMillis = 2000

    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "transition")

    val color1 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[0],
        targetValue = colors[1],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color1"
    )

    val color2 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[1],
        targetValue = colors[2],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color2"
    )

    val color3 by transition.animateColor(
        initialValue = colors[2],
        targetValue = colors[0],
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ),
        label = "color3"
    )


    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .drawWithCache {
                val brush = Brush.radialGradient(listOf(color1, color2, color3))

                onDrawBehind {
                    drawRect(brush = brush)
                }
            }
    )
}

Here is an improved version that works with any list of colors:

@Composable
fun App4(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow)
    val durationMillis = 2000


    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "transition")


    val stateColors = mutableListOf<State<Color>>()

    for (i in colors.indices) {
        val currentItem = colors[i]
        val nextItem = colors[(i + 1) % colors.size]

        val stateColor = transition.animateColor(
            initialValue = currentItem,
            targetValue = nextItem,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(durationMillis, easing = LinearEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
            ),
            label = "color$i"
        )

        stateColors.add(stateColor)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .drawWithCache {
                val brush = Brush.radialGradient(stateColors.map { it.value })
                onDrawBehind {
                    drawRect(brush = brush)
                }
            }
    )
}



@NicolasDUBOSCQ Kindly accept the answer if it helped. Thanks!
